# Cant add in-app product for testing without wallet account

Tags: android, in-app-billing, google-checkout

Recently, I buy an`Deleveloper Console account` for publishing my android application. After payment (25$), I got an account and I can upload my APK file. However, when I try to add some in-app products for testing before publishing to market, it's required an `google checkout account`. But I can't register that account because of my unsupported country. And of course, I can't test In-app billing. Does any one know how to change my country to get an `google checkout account` or  how to test `In-app billing` products without `google checkout account`? Thank you very much!

Comment: Am not an Android developer so _I might be wrong about this_. If you're just doing **sandbox testing** then you can create a **sandbox account** in any country (obviously choose one that is supported). **Sandbox** are test accounts and are completely separate from your **production** account. Again, note my disclaimer - I'm basing my comment on same APIs but for web (not apps) where sandbox is available.

Comment: From the previous Developer Console UI version, I can test without `google checkout account`, but not this version!

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html#billing-testing-static) you can use predefined test product ids such as `android.test.purchased`, `android.test.canceled` and so forth. However you can't test subscriptions in such way

Answer (score 1):

I found my own answer! All I must do, is to change country (to supported-country) in `Setting` of `Google Wallet account`. After changing it, I can easily create `google checkout account` without any error. Hope this answer will help any one who get the same problem!

Comment: I think you may need to clarify this - because there are 2 types of Wallet accounts - **BUYER and MERCHANT/Dev**. The former (BUYER), supports more countries (obviously), than the latter. In other words, there are more countries supported for Buyers than there are Merchants. For example, in the legacy Google Checkout product, it was **only US/UK for merchants/dev accounts**, but you can have BUYERS in all countries that Wallet supports.

Answer (score -1):

you cannot, what I suggest you try and do is setup an account via an anonymous proxy and a paypal account.